# NSArray Set property not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Basically what i am trying to do is make a network refresh and fetch objects, store it in a nsmutable array in my app delegate. Then i have a listviewController which uses that mutable array to display data.

Setting nsarray is not working here is the code:

```
//Appdelegate code called after pulldown to refresh is done on listview:

     [ListView setArrayElements:(NSMutableArray*)sortedArray ];
      NSLog(@"sortedArray count:%d",sortedArray);  
     NSLog(@"ListView Array count:%d",[ListView.ArrayElements count]);

     Result i get in log : "sortedArray count:12" (which is perfect)&"ListView Array count:0" (this is not the right result)
```

Comment: Try with BeginUpdates and EndUpdate methods, I use them without problem

Comment: I bet you're using an NSTimer for refreshing the table view after the estimated time for the request elapses. But you uderestimate the time dilatation, and you refresh the view before it actually gets the new data.

Comment: Why you refresh with a timer at all? Why not call reloadTableView right after the reload of data?

Comment: Could you also post the code where you call `-(void)reloadTableView:(NSTimer *)timer4`. For all we know, that code may very well be running in the background and UI updates should be done on the main thread only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to assume without seeing more of your code but how do you define the `ArrayElements` property? It may not be retaining itself and you may not have initialized it when the `ListView` object is created.

Let me know if this works;

Make sure `ArrayElements` is created in your `ListView.h` like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ArrayElements;
```

Or on `-init` or `-viewDidLoad` of your `ListView`,

```
self.ArrayElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Don't forget to release what you retained:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     //.....
     [ArrayElements release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.mTableView reloadData];
 }
```

use this method

Comment: It is working fine when view is loaded, provlem is only when i do a pull to refresh. data is loaded with new elemnts

Comment: hey who is downvoting my answer. its working fine for questioners project. then why downvote. can explain problem in my code????????

Answer (score -4):

Do not make the UITableView object as a property. Just use tableView object , remove 'self.' portion.
Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Nope still the same.. i think the problem is with the nsarray not refreshing in ListView when i do setArrayElements. Coz i still get rong count after pull to refresh is done

Comment: Why he have to do that?! Why he can't keep UITableView as a property?